# Connecting to Bigquery by Python: ProjectId and DatasetId must be non-empty

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, connection

I wrote the below script to connect Big Query to Python by SDK as below:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client=bigquery.Client(project='My First Project')
sql="select * from austin_311.311_service_requests"
query_job=client.query(sql)
```

I face the below error:

> BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/My%20First%20Project/jobs?prettyPrint=false: ProjectId and DatasetId must be non-empty

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: `project='My First Project'` <- this is wrong. You should put your project ID and not your project name

Comment: I've also received this when supplying the wrong project id.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be clear, and echo @ferregina-pelona and @cnstlungu's comments, the issue is the wrong `project_id` in your initial Big Query authentication.  You should have provided a legit `project_id`.  I believe the posted answer below "resolves" the issue by avoiding the initial problem.

Please make sure that the `project_id` you specify is one that is listed by the `gcloud` command:

`gcloud projects list`

Posting this as an answer, in case it helps anyone as @에스파파's does not really address the issue, only circumvents it, and because looking in comments isn't as obvious as an answer.

Comment: i tried this, its a good answer to find the project! but the command should be 'gcloud projects list'
and then you get the projects which should replace with my first project. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the problem by offering credentials for the google BigQuery Client.
Check codes below.

```py
# https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html
from google.oauth2 import service_account

json_account_info = #{service_account_info}
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    json_account_info)
...

from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

sql="select * from austin_311.311_service_requests"
query_job=client.query(sql)
```