# How do I use gbq from pandas.io to pull BigQuery data into Colab?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-colaboratory, pandas.dataframe.to-gbq

I have been at this for over six hours and cannot figure out why this process is so difficult. I watched every YouTube video, went through every tutorial, but they all assume extensive knowledge of some step of the process that isn't covered in their tutorial.

I'm in BigQuery Sandbox. I did the tutorial offered in the right sidebar of [this page](https://console.cloud.google.com/welcome?walkthrough_id=bigquery--bigquery-quickstart-query-public-dataset&project=warm-alliance-396017).

At the end of this tutorial, you are given instructions on how to query the `usa_1910_2013` table from the `usa_names` dataset. Here's how I'm left at the end of the tutorial:

[image: BigQuery screenshot]

Then I tried to use that SQL query and pull the resulting data into a Colab notebook using `pandas.io gbq`:

[image: Colab screenshot]

I get an error saying: "BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/bquxjob_76da2ac5_189fab01b3f/jobs?prettyPrint=false: ProjectId and DatasetId must be non-empty"

In my first screenshot (of BigQuery), where is my project id? Where is my DatasetID? What do I type in the `read_gbq()` function for it to run properly?

Comment: Hi NaiveBae, Can you check this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823768/connecting-to-bigquery-by-python-projectid-and-datasetid-must-be-non-empty) Is this useful or not for your query ?